# Poor quality rendering of parametric curve in Processing (Java)

Tags: java, processing, pdf-rendering, parametric-equations

Using Processing 2.0b6 on a Windows 7 PC, I've grokked some GeoGebra code^ to write a sketch that plots a parametric curve (the example I've been playing with is a cardioid). It does this by generating a point distribution that is 'curvature aware'.

A horrendously messy - but working - version of the sketch is here^^, and a stripped down version that includes an array of points belonging to the cardioid but not the curve-plotting algorithm that generated it is here^^^.

The problem is the way in which the curve is rendered as a polyline in the Processing display window when each of the points in the point distribution is connected. This [image](http://lunarbrogue.appspot.com/parametric_plotting/cardioid_p5.png) shows how hairy and lumpy the rendering is, but... and this is the nub of the issue... check out this beautifully smooth pdf [rendering](http://lunarbrogue.appspot.com/parametric_plotting/cardioid_p5.pdf).

What's going on here? The (almost) flawless vector graphic makes me confident that the problem isn't the point distribution but rather something to do with the to-pixel rendering for the display window (I know my terminology is imprecise here). Is the shifting and scaling affecting things? Is the to-pdf converter doing something fancy with the point distribution?

I'm puzzled. Any help / insights would be massively appreciated.

By the way, if anyone's interested, I've also coded up the cardioid in Java (again, the code is messy but functional):

lunarbrogue.appspot.com/parametric_plotting/cardioid.java

and openframeworks:

lunarbrogue.appspot.com/parametric_plotting/main.cpp

lunarbrogue.appspot.com/parametric_plotting/testApp.h

lunarbrogue.appspot.com/parametric_plotting/testApp.cpp

with resulting pdf:

lunarbrogue.appspot.com/parametric_plotting/cardioid_cpp.pdf

^ code.google.com/p/kojo/source/browse/geogebra/euclidian/DrawParametricCurve.java?repo=geogebra&r=11b69dffe5e3d7c4a26d1c824823b7adbe9fef64&spec=svn.geogebra.cf6dc85691114377a23559b7281b70e3c6a07302

^^ lunarbrogue.appspot.com/parametric_plotting/ParametricCurvePlotter2.pde

^^^ lunarbrogue.appspot.com/parametric_plotting/Cardioid1.pde

Comment: Generally your question should include relevant source code.  When the links rot (which _will_ happen), this question becomes useless to the community.

Comment: have you tried smooth() ?

Comment: Petros: absolutely. It was no good. I'm not sure poor-quality or non-existent anti-aliasing is the problem.